# Function returned when loading .npy file in python3

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.4

I have stored a dict as diversity.npy. the dict structure: {key: array}.
when I use np.load to load diversity.npy:

```
diver=np.load('diversity.npy').item()
print(diver)
```

if the environment is python27 ,it is correct to load the data. However function object is loaded in python34.

```
<function diversity at 0x7fc0741977b8>
```

how to fix?

Comment: It's not an error. Are you sure that you ran the same code in Python3 ?

Comment: Show code how did you save diversity.npy

Comment: the code: np.save('diversity',diver).....the diver is a dict....I ran same code in both environment

Comment: Show what contains the diver variable.

Comment: Since pickle format may differ between 2.7 and 3.x, you can consider storing a e.g. JSON file instead.

Comment: the diver variable is a dict, such as { key：NxN array}................................I have try to use json, but it give me some error.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple dictionary save in Py3.5

```
In [157]: dd = {'x':np.array(10)}
In [158]: np.save('dd.npy', dd)
In [159]: data = np.load('dd.npy')
In [160]: data
Out[160]: array({'x': array(10)}, dtype=object)
In [161]: data.item()
Out[161]: {'x': array(10)}
```

It wrapped the dictionary in an object array, and saved that (using dictionary pickle).  `item()` takes the dictionary out of the array wrapper.

`pickle` has problems crossing from `py2` to `py3`.